# add comments custom fields after user is logged in

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, comments, hooks

I want to add two custom fields inside comments on a CPT after the user is logged in on.

This is the code for creating the custom fields:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {

if( is_singluar('debate') ) {


    /* Add our custom fields */
    $fields['first'] = '<p class="comment-form-first"><label for="first">' . 
                     __( 'Age' ) . 
                     '</label>' . 
                     '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true).'" /></p>';


    $fields['second'] = '<p class="comment-form-second"><label for="second">' . 
                       __( 'Town' ) . 
                       '</label>' .
                      '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'disagree', true).'" /></p>';

    return $fields;

}

}

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

LATER EDIT: 
some relevant code from my theme comments.php file:

```
// Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in
if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || is_user_logged_in() ) {
comment_form( $args );
}
?>
```

The current code adds the fields when the user is not logged in, and I want to add them after the user is logged in.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

```
if(is_singular('debate') && is_user_logged_in()) {
  // ...
}
```

(Note: `is_singular` is misspelled in your code.)

Comment: Tried this but it's not working, I mean is not adding the custom fields...

Comment: Then you need to provide more information

Comment: I've updated my question with some relevant additional info, please check it out!

Comment: The edit doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't know what relevant information  I can provide, can you help me with this?

Comment: If I remove the `&& is_user_logged_in()` the fields are added when the user is not logged in so the code is working. It might be something wrong with `&& is_user_logged_in()` maybe I need to add a different function for checking this. Do you have any idea what's going wrong with this?

Comment: Sorry, I lost track of this question but you have marked it as "accepted". I assume you worked out what was wrong?